# 1 inch all around

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm writing a paper in A4 paper. I want to set all margins to be precisely 1 inch. I'm using the geometry package with the following parameters.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead]{geometry}
```

However the result does not seem to be what is specified. The left and right margins are being set to something like 1.3 inches, while the top and bottom margins are being set to 1.5 inches.

**Question:** Which command should I use to set all margins to precisely one inch?

Comment: What you do is correct, you can try with `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,nohead,showframe]{geometry}` the `showframe` just for help

Comment: Try `\usepackage[margin=2truein]{geometry}`. The main point is `truein`, which gives "true" inches, rather than `in`, which can be scaled.

Comment: @Andrew Unless `\mag` is set to a different value than its default 1000, there is no difference between units and their `true` version. I don't think `\mag` is touched upon by the OP.

Comment: Welcome! We need a complete minimal working example which demonstrates the problem when we copy-paste-compile your code. You can also add `verbose` to the options and `geometry` will print the results of its calculations to the console and log.